# Do HTML imports provide any form of Javascript encapsulation?

Tags: javascript, html, encapsulation, html-imports

I've just read about the use of HTML imports for component encapsulation.

`<link rel=import href="import.html">`

The file `import.html` would include everything that's needed for the component.

One big problem, though: Javascript functions and variables inside `import.html` become part of the `window` namespace, which means there's no encapsulation whatsoever.
Two different components which happen to have a function with the same name will collide and one of the functions will be overridden.

Do HTML imports provide any form of javascript encapsulation that didn't exist before?

---

**Example:**

**`main.html`**

```
<link rel=import href="import1.html">
<link rel=import href="import2.html">

<script>
console.log( moduleFunction() ) ; //`moduleFunction` can be called as if it was defined in the outter document
</script>
```

**`import1.html`**

```
<script>
function moduleFunction(){
    return 'module1' ;
}
</script>
```

**`import2.html`**

```
<script>
function moduleFunction(){
    return 'module2' ;
}
</script>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why would `import.html` include scripts?

Comment: _"One big problem, though: Javascript functions and variables inside import.html become part of the `window` namespace"_ Can you include code at Question demonstrating issue?

Comment: @Getfree Check the answer I posted might help you

Comment: @Getfree Why would `<script>` be included in HTML of a file intended to be imported at `<link>` element? Why would the functions in the HTML have the same name?

Comment: @guest271314 I'm trying to find out if HTML imports provide any new form of javascript encapsulation than the already existing ones. i.e. `Objects`, `iframes`, `closures`. Something that could prevent name collisions between two or more third-party libraries/components.

Comment: Different `<script>` elements having functions with the same name is not exclusive to `<link rel="import">` elements. That can occur at an HTML `document` having multiple `<script>` elements. If you are in control of the HTML documents you can remove `<script>` elements altogether from the HTML and load scripts separately

Comment: @guest271314, the example demonstrates that HTML imports don't provide encapsulation (at least not in the way I'm doing it). So, the question is: Is there any other way of using HTML imports that could prodide javascript encapsulation?

Comment: @Getfree The simplest solution would be to check if the identifier is defined at `"import2.html"`, use or overwrite the existing identifier; or define the variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. However, wrapping everything in a function or having a global object that you store all your variables in inside `import.html` would work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you already had the answer.

> Javascript functions and variables inside import.html become part of the window namespace, which means there's no encapsulation whatsoever.
>   Two different components which happen to have a function with the same name will collide and one of the functions will be overridden.
>
> Do HTML imports provide any form of javascript encapsulation that didn't exist before?

Not much from the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-imports/#scripts-imports).

[HTML5 Rocks](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/#usingcontent):

> Script in the import is executed in the context of the window that contains the importing document. So window.document refers to the main page document.

This is [not widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=imports).

Answer (score 0):

> Do HTML imports provide any form of javascript encapsulation that
>   didn't exist before?

No, not the use of `rel="import"` alone. It is up to the developer to incorporate the appropriate logic into the procedure if two separate HTML documents could potentially include `<script>` elements where functions are declared that have the same identifiers, respectively; and to decide which identifier will be used at main `window`.

`<link>` You can use `let`, `try..catch`. Since `<link>` elements are blocking, see [link elements block DOM parsing too](https://remysharp.com/2011/06/08/link-elements-block-dom-parsing-too), we use the order of the `<link>` in HTML to arrange the check for the declaration of the identifier. That is, `moduleFunction` should always be defined from `"import1.html"`, unless the requirement is to implement a different order of checking for specific variables being declared or not

```
<script>    
  let moduleFunction;    
  try {
    moduleFunction = function moduleFunction() {
        return 'module1';
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("module 1 error", err)
  }      
</script>
```

```
<script>
  moduleFunction = moduleFunction || void 0;
  if (!moduleFunction) {
    try {
      moduleFunction = function moduleFunction() {
        return 'module2';
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("module2 error", err)
    }
  }
</script>
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/lzHkc8pydD7q17ldgnrq?p=preview